# Edit text cursor position

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to place the cursor after 2 spaces in `EditText`. Can anybody tell me how to do that? I am trying to use

```
et.setSelection(2);
```

but its not working.

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: Use this `android:paddingFromLeft="2dp"`

Comment: Thank you Manish.. its just done in 1 line.. no need to do through coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use android:paddingLeft= "2dp"

Answer (score 4):

Try to use like this..before set the the cursor position there must be some text at the starting there is no text that's why it is not working..
so try like this..

```
et.setText("   ");
et.setSelection(2);
```